# How do I solve this exponential function? $2^{-100x} = (0.5)^{x-4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

How do I solve for $x$?

$2^{-100x} = (0.5)^{x-4}$

Comment: is it $(.5)^{x-4}$ or $(.5)^x-4$?

Comment: First write $(0.5)^{x-4}=2^{-(x-4)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you need the same base:  So $0.5=\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1}$

Thus, $2^{100x}=(2^{-1})^{x-4}=2^{4-x}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
-100x\ln\left(2\right)
=
\left(x - 4\right)\ln\left(0.5\right)
=
x\ln\left(0.5\right)- 4\ln\left(0.5\right)\,,
\quad
x
=
{4\ln\left(0.5\right) \over 100\ln\left(2\right) + \ln\left(0.5\right)}
$$

$\ln\left(0.5\right) = -\ln\left(2\right)$
$$
\color{#ff0000}{\large x}
=
{-4\ln\left(2\right) \over 100\ln\left(2\right) - \ln\left(2\right)}
=
\color{#ff0000}{-\,{4 \over 99}}
$$